# Definition of extension for relations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Consider the following definition from Sohrab, Basic Real Analysis:

### Definition 1.2.4 (Restriction, Extension)

Let $f, g\subset X\times Y$ be two relations. If $f\subset g$, we say that $f$ is a restriction of $g$ or that $g$ is an extension of $f$. If $\text{dom}(f)=D$, then $f\subset g$ is also denoted by $f=g|_D$.

### Question / example

**NOTE: We are working with relations, not necessarily functions**

Consider the case $X=\{1\}$, $Y=\{1,2\}$, $f\subset g\subset X\times Y$, $f=\{(1,1)\}$, $g=\{(1,1),(1,2)\}$. $f\subset g$ but the notation $f=g\mid_{\text{dom}(f)}$ is misleading or wrong: $\text{dom}(f)=\{1\}$, $f(1)=\{1\}$, but $g(1)=g_{\text{dom}(f)}(1)=\{1,2\}$.

What I mean is that althought $f\subset g$, $f\neq g\mid_{\text{dom}(f)}$ in the common meaning.

**EDIT** Question: What is the minimal change to the definition of Sohrab to make it correct?

Comment: You are totally correct, but what is your question?

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: Well, the correct definition should be $g|_D = \{ (x,y) \in g : x \in D \}$.

Comment: ok, thank you. Interesting would also be to know/conjecture, what could have been in the head of the author to write $f\subset g$. I do not think it is pure chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the definition given of $g|_D$ is incorrect:

1. As you point out, perhaps $f$ restricts from $g$ too much: while it has the domain $D$, it doesn't contain *all* the pairs from $g$ whose first element was in $D$.
2. But there is another problem: we want $g|_D$ to be defined even when $g$ is not defined on some of the elements of $D$. For example, let $X = Y = \{1,2,3\}$, $D = \{1,2\}$, $g = \{(1,1),(1,3),(3,3)\}$. If $f = \{(1,1),(1,3)\}$ then we would probably like to say $f = g|_D$, but the definition in question doesn't cover it because $\operatorname{dom} f = \{1\} \ne D$.

There are different, equivalent ways to give a correct definition.

- The usual definition would be
  $$
  g|_D  = \Big\{(x,y) \::\; x \in D \text{ and } (x,y) \in g\Big\}
  $$
- More concisely,
  $$
  g|_D = g \cap (D \times Y)
  $$
- More along the lines of the definition given in your book, we could also say
  $$
  f = g|_D \quad\textbf{if} \quad f \subseteq g, \text{dom f} \subseteq D, \text{ and } 
  f(x) = g(x) \text{ for all } x \in D.
  $$

Comment: Interesting and the last line is what I was actually looking for: a preserving change. Thanks.

Comment: @LiPo You're welcome.